# Can a Enum pointer point to a constant value?

Tags: c++, pointers, enums, segmentation-fault

I am working on some code where I have an 'enum' defined to describe the type of error.
Whenever a certain function is called, it takes an 'enum pointer' as a parameter. The function will then set the passed in error variable with a 'constant enum' value. When I run the program I get a run-time error. I have provided some of the code to describe my issue:

```
enum error
{
    No_Exist=0, 
    No_Error,
    Unknown,
};

bool process_something(..., error *err)
{
    ....
    ....
    ....
    *err = No_Error;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    error *err_val; 
    if(process_something(...,err_val))
    {
    .....
    .....
    }
    .....
    return (0);
}
```

I want to know whether I can assign the pointer enum variable with the value 'No_Error' or not?

Comment: You will first need to initialise the pointer to something, `error *err_val;` points to nowhere (anywhere). Better still, just use it as a value (`error err_val;`) and pass it by reference.

Comment: Or, in other words, the line `*err = No_Error;` can be fine, it's just that the way you're calling the function is wrong.

Comment: @Niall You mean if I take simple variable as 'error err' and while calling the function I pass the address as '&err'. There will not be any segmentation fault.

Comment: Correct. Else change the signature to `process_something(..., error& err)` and call it as `if(process_something(...,err))` (with  `error err = Unknown;`)

Comment: Okay this helped me. I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ever you see a function like:

```
void foo(int*);
```

It doesn't mean you need to pass an explicitly declared `int*` variable. Following is wrong usage:

```
int* p;
foo(p);
```

Following is correct, but not proper:

```
int* p;
int a;
p=&a;
foo(p); // p points to a
```

Following is also correct (but again not proper, IMO):

```
 int* p;
 p = new int;
 foo(p); // p points to allocated memory
```

The most correct usage (as per the problem in hand) would be:

```
int a;
foo(&a);
```

Remember that `int*` (or any `T*`) says that *pass me an address*, and doesn't say pass me a pointer. Another example would be with reference. If a function is like:

```
void bar(int&);
```

Doesn't mean you must declare a int-reference, and pass it:

```
int a;
int &r = a;
bar(r);
```

But instead pass `a` itself. Function needs a reference (L-value).

Comment: When you say "ill formed" you mean "bad style". In C++, "ill-formed" means "not well formed" which (citing from the C++11 standard) means "C++ program constructed according to the syntax rules, diagnosable semantic rules, and the One Definition
Rule". In this sense, which I would prefer because it is the one the C++ standard gives the word, the examples you gave are not ill-formed.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
int main()
{
    error *err_val; 
    if(process_something(...,err_val))
```

should be:

```
int main()
{
    error err_val; 
    if(process_something(..., &err_val))
```

You need to pass the address of a valid `error` to create a pointer to somewhere `process_something()` can actually write. Your code triggers undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Now if you must use what you are using you should do it by reference.

For example,

```
int readnumber(string userinput, bool* ok);// or your enum instead of a boolean
//
bool okay;
auto val = readstring(someinput,&okay);
if (!okay)
{
    cout << "Something weird but we don't want that to crash our program";
}
```

Comment: These 'errors' are not 'exceptions' they are just used for logging purpose. Enums are defined error that we set after a procees( 'function') Its a piece of code just to solve my issue.